# Creating a method to reverse an array String[] and then checking if it is a palindrome

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

I had to create two methods. One to take an array of Strings and reverse their order. Using `assertArrayEquals` to test, the backwards method passed. Then I had to create a method to check if a String array is a palindrome, but that test if failing. I thought that maybe I messed something up in the backwards method, but I tested that 12 different ways. I may be really tired, but what did I do wrong here?

```java
public static String[] backwards(String[] array) {
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length / 2; index++) {
        String string = array[index];
        array[index] = array[array.length - index - 1];
        array[array.length - index - 1] = string;
    }
    return array;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String[] array) {
    if (array == backwards(array)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with this code:

#1 You are editing the array in place. So the backwards method does not only return a reversed array, it changes the original array.

#2 You are comparing two arrays with `==` which will check if it's the same instance. You can use `Arrays.equals` instead.

```java
public static String[] backwards(String[] array) {
    String[] resArray = new String[array.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        resArray[index] = array[array.length - index - 1];
    }
    return resArray;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.equals(array, backwards(array));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since *Java 9* you can use [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) and [`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-T:A-T:A-) methods:

```java
public static String[] backwards(String[] array) {
    return IntStream.iterate(array.length - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> array[i])
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.compare(array, backwards(array)) == 0;
}
```

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = {"backwards", "palindrome", "abracadabra", "abcdcba"};

    System.out.println(isPalindrome(arr)); // false
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(arr[3].split(""))); // true
}
```